# How to Retrieve Related Records using plugin in Dynamics crm

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

In dynamics crm records has subgrids. subgrids associated with other records. Now how Retrieve related Records using plugin. Any references would appreciated.

Comment: edited with correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a subgrid displays related records connected by a relationship, 1:N or N:N.

You need to get the relationship name and after using the right methods.

Relevant MSDN articles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509021.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309538.aspx

Comment: thanks for suggesting

Comment: i know queryexpression to retrieve entites.but how to do query expres to retrieve subgrid records.how to use relationship in query expressions.could you plz clarify me

Answer (score 1):

In plugin you can't directly access what you have displayed in Form Grid. If records inside grid are associated with main entity the you can retrieve those records by querying (QueryExpression, Fetch XML or Linq) on related entity where they are associated to main entity.

For example code have look at the following links:

[Retrieve related entity data](http://mscrmkb.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/crm-2011-retrieve-related-entity-data.html)

[Retrieve associated records (N:N related)](http://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/retrieve-associated-records-nn-related/)

Comment: thanks for suggesting

Comment: which relationship that subgrid using.shall i use n:n relationship.if yes means how to do that.could plz clarify me

Comment: Go to the Settings > Customization > Customize the System and Expand entity in left side panel. You will see the relationships under it. Identify the relationship type there.

Comment: yes.i found the relationships.but how to find the subgrid relationships

Comment: Open the form and then click on 'Customize'. Double click on Subgrid tab under common (left side panel). Relationship properties will be opened. Click on `Name` tab, relationship name will be displayed in Name textbox. However, You have already accepted the above answer so I would suggest you to open another question for this discussion or Accept the answer which is more helpful for you. Regards

Comment: i double click that subgrid under that i did'nt find any common tab inside subgrid

Comment: Have you opened the form in Customize mode?

Comment: yes.common tab is there on left side.but you told in subgrid

Comment: open the form in Customize mode first. It will open the form in edit mode. In Edit mode, double click on the tab with you use to navigate to sub grid.